# Is there a way to loop URL for fetching JSON data in android studio?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am creating an android app that fetch JSON data from an url using Volley

```
http://10.180.243.14:8080/api/departments/1
```

This will fetch all department 1's employees whose JSON is as such:

```
{
"id": 1,
"deptName": "Raj Bhavan",
"logo": [],
"contacts": [
{
"contactId": 12,
"empName": "John",
"designation": "Director",
"mobile": "9862136415",
"landlineOffice": "123456",
"landlineRes": "2334567",
"fax": "555679",
"email": "administer@gmail.com"
},
{
"contactId": 19,
"empName": "Samuel ",
"designation": "Software Developer",
"mobile": "9876542019",
"landlineOffice": "234567",
"landlineRes": "2320398",
"fax": "456678",
"email": "sam@ymail.com"
}
]
}
```

I can fetch this correctly using volley.
But I want to fetch all JSON data from department 2,3,4,etc.

Below is my MainActivity.java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextView mTextViewResult;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    private TextView mTextViewDept;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mTextViewDept =findViewById(R.id.text_view_dept);
        mTextViewResult=findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
        Button buttonParse=findViewById(R.id.button_parse);

        mQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        buttonParse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                jsonParse();
            }
        });

    }

    private void jsonParse(){

        String url="http://10.180.243.14:8080/api/departments/1";
        JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
                                Log.i("tt","deptJson"+response);

                                try {
                                    JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("contacts");

                                    String deptName=response.getString("deptName");


                                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                        JSONObject contact=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                        int contactId=contact.getInt("contactId");
                                        String empName=contact.getString("empName");
                                        String designation=contact.getString("designation");

                                        mTextViewResult.append(empName+","+ String.valueOf(contactId)+","+designation+"\n\n");

                                    }

                                    mTextViewDept.setText(deptName);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                    },new Response.ErrorListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });

        mQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

This will fetch JSON data of only department 1's.

I expect to fetch all JSONs from

```
http://10.180.243.14:8080/api/departments/2
http://10.180.243.14:8080/api/departments/3
http://10.180.243.14:8080/api/departments/4
...
```

I have created the API myself, and data will be added in the future.
Is there a way to loop through all the urls dynamically?

Comment: do you know about loops? start at 1, end at 4.

Comment: Yes, sir I do..

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this
int MAX_OBJECT = 100;
for (int i =1;i<MAX_OBJECT;i++){
     String no = String.valueOf(i);
     jsonParse(no);
}

private void jsonParse(final String NoOfDepartment){
String url="http://10.180.243.14:8080/api/departments/"+NoOfDepartment;
.......
}
```

Comment: Please add more details and explanations on your answer.

Comment: I replace previuos onClick with @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Try this
                int MAX_OBJECT = 100;
                for (int i =1;i<MAX_OBJECT;i++){
                    String no = String.valueOf(i);
                    jsonParse(no);
                }
            }

Comment: also jsonParse with private void jsonParse(final String NoOfDepartment){
        String url="http://10.180.243.14:8080/api/departments/"+NoOfDepartment;